# Arcserve incremental backup to network drive on weekday and full backup at monthend to a USB drive

Tags: backup

i wish to keep the backup as simple, fast as possible

weekday : incremental backup to network drive, admin no need to care about it
monthend : full backup to a USB drive, then admin will remove the USB to another location for security fire issue

is it possible to config at Arcserve?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes to separated policies and you will be good, there will be a problem though, with restores. Because to restore full machine you will have to attach usb back to it's location. If you are not using synthetic backup then you need all backups be on place to fully recover machine.